# Python how to trigger execute command when value changed

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I have a question about python, I am saving the current months and year using strftime() in the format of %y %m so the value will display like '17 01'. This is how I get the year and month

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
strftime("%y %m" ,gmtime())
print strftime()
```

I am currently using SQLite and I wish to call a function to check in my DB means that before the unique ID was generated and display. I wish to know that whether there is changes in month ?? if yes, the auto increment need to start from 0, if no the auto increment will just continue

Both of the value will be display as a ID and will be save as int to the database, and after the year and month have a auto increment integer (the string will look like these

(y)(m)(auto increment)

17 10 001

how to write a code when there is changes on %y or %m , I will trigger a command and run

```
db.engine.execute("ALTER TALBE myDB.myTable AUTO_INCREMENT=0;")
```

Comment: I have no idea how to do it, because I'm new to python what can I think of is hard code it by declare 12 if function, but after that I realized it can't be done. If I declare the %y or %m == 01 the increment set to 0 it will not work. So I'm posting and asking for a tutorial or any solution that might work. Do you have any experience in this ??

Comment: When and where do you want to check for changes?  In the DB, or in your script, or somewhere else?

Comment: I want to check inside my DB, means that before the unique ID was generated and display. I wish to know that whether there is changes in month or year ?? if yes, the auto increment need to start from 1, if no the auto increment will just continue

Comment: So you're looking for a trigger function inside the DB?  What DB are you using?

Comment: yaya, Im currently using SQLite. Do you know know about this ?

Comment: Not extensively. It's best to update your question to make this clearer.